# How to use logging.BufferingFormatter

Tags: python, logging

Python logging tutorial [says](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#useful-handlers):

> For formatting multiple messages in a batch, instances of
>   BufferingFormatter can be used. In addition to the format string
>   (which is applied to each message in the batch), there is provision
>   for header and trailer format strings.

Here is how `BufferingFormatter.format` is implemented:

```
def format(self, records):
    """
    Format the specified records and return the result as a string.
    """
    rv = ""
    if len(records) > 0:
        rv = rv + self.formatHeader(records)
        for record in records:
            rv = rv + self.linefmt.format(record)
        rv = rv + self.formatFooter(records)
    return rv
```

As we can see, it accepts a bunch of records instead of a single record, so this fails whenever you try to attach this formatter to any handler. Besides, the whole idea assumes some special buffering behaviour from the handler.

Thereby, my question is: how is this formatter supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be using [`BufferingHandler`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BufferingHandler) in order to use corresponding `BufferingFormatter`s.

Comment: The only existing BufferingHandler is MemoryHandler (which is a buffering decorator for any other handler), but it merely redirects calls to the handler underneath and ignores the own formatter. Does that actually mean that I'll have to write my own handler?

Comment: Yep. Some Googling turned up one example: http://compbio.cs.toronto.edu/repos/snowflock/xen-3.0.3/tools/python/logging/logging-0.4.9.2/test/log_test9.py